# Role with policy that restricts access to folder in s3 bucket getting ignored

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I've got this policy (called "backup") assigned to a role (called "sync"):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowSync",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::My_Bucket"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "db_backups/example.com/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowGetPut",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::My_Bucket/db_backups/example.com/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

1. Before assigning the sync role containing the backup policy to an instance, the instance cannot access resources in the bucket. This is as expected.
2. After I assign the instance to they sync role, the instance can access objects in the designated folder in the policy. This is expected.
3. However, what's unexpected is that the instance now also has access to all objects in the bucket no matter what folder they are in. It's like the restrictions in place in the policy are getting ignore.

The bucket does not grant access to the public.

**UPDATE**

The problem appears to be related to a bucket policy I had in place:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1607462323232",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::My_Bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::My_Bucket/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:SourceVpce": "vpce-aaaaadddddfffff"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "can access objects"? Can they just List objects, or can they Get and Put too? Can you also confirm that adding this policy is the only change between situations #1 and #3? Something certainly sounds strange.

Comment: The instance can get/put and sync with the entire aws s3 bucket on the command line after adding the instance to the role with this policy.  Adding the role to the instance is the only change.

Comment: I modified the policy by removinv the second statement with the "Get/PutObject" action and it still lets me download and upload objects to any folder in the bucket. Super weird.

Comment: So you're saying that the policy now only grants ListBucket, but the instance can still Get/Put objects? Is it possible that the instance is using credentials saved on the instance (in `~/.aws/credentials`) rather than the IAM Role? It has to be getting the permissions from _somewhere_.

Comment: If I remove the policy from the role and revoke all privileges policy with "AWSRevokeOlderSessions", the instance can no longer get/put objects. I'm new to working with roles and policies so I may be totally out to lunch, but it sure seems like it has something to do with the policy.

Comment: I wouldn't think you'd need to use `AWSRevokeOlderSessions` -- the changes should work immediately. The Revoke will take away permissions from any earlier session, which would likely include the instance. (EC2 instance credentials are refreshed every 6 hours.) Therefore, you might want to detach the IAM Role from the instance, and attach it again. Then, test it again and try adding back the policy one bit at-a-time and see which part gives them the undesired access.

Comment: I think I'm starting to figure things out. From an earlier attempt at giving another service access, I had a bucket policy in place that allowed anything from an vpce permission to get/put/list. When I removed that policy, access was denied to all but the allowed folders in the policy.

Comment: What I'm confused by is why the bucket policy was only followed when a role was added to the instance. I'm going to add the bucket policy to OP.

Comment: The Bucket Policy is granting List/Get/Put to anyone as long as the request comes from the VPC-Endpoint. This is _additive_, so the instance would be able to access the bucket if _either_ the IAM Role or the Bucket Policy is granting such permission.

Comment: I was originally trying to do this using access points instead of folders. Somewhere in the documentation I had read the permissions in the bucket had to allow the same permission that the access point needed.

Comment: Yeah, it was on this page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/access-points-policies.html "For an application or user to be able to access objects through an access point, both the access point and the underlying bucket must permit the request." I'm not using access points anymore so I guess it doesn't matter. I'm not really sure when an access point would be used.

Comment: Access Points are a way of restricting access to a bucket to much smaller groups, such as "Only resources in this VPC can access that bucket".